# Laravel specifying connection for migrations

Tags: php, laravel

According to documentation to specify connection to use when migrating DB is either

```
protected $connection = "mysql_shared";
```

or

```
Schema::connection("mysql_shared")->create(...);
```

I have defined a connection in database.php just like this:

```
"mysql_shared" =>[
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => "192.168.0.100",
        'port' => "3306",
        'database' => "db",
        'username' => "user",
        'password' => "password",
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],
```

So far according to docs schema upon migration should choose the connection and migrate. But there is a big BUT. it simply doesn't work unless I go to env file and add

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql_shared
```

according to logs and common sense it tries to use the default connection due to `'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),`

`Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = forge and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')`

Comment: @TimLewis https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#setting-the-migration-connection here it explicitly says that this is the connection to use specifically for migration

Comment: Ah, this is my bad! I thought you were setting that property on a Model (since that's what your title says) Sorry about that! Comment removed 

Comment: @TimLewis no no, it is for the Schema definition, basically it does not use the connections unless I set it to a default connection. which is weird.

Comment: No worries, we're on the same page now. As long as this `'mysql_shared'` key is within the `'connections' => [ ]` array of `config/database.php`, your code should work fine... I'm not sure why it would be trying to use the `'mysql'` connection. Let me try to do some testing to replicate this issue; it's not one I've personally seen before (i.e. multi-connection db/migrations have worked fine for me in the past, might be a new issue in Laravel 9 though).

Comment: Try `php artisan migrate --database=mysql_shared` instead.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden yeah but what if some schemas are from different connections ? for example I run 3 databases. one for application and it related stuff. another one contains all users for local services, and third one is specifically for Laravel sessions and website data.

Comment: I had problems with Laravel when migrating multiple databases. A migration command per database was for me the best solution. You will need a migration table in every database anyway.